# GWT onPreviewNativeEvent runs 2 times when key is pressed

Tags: java, events, gwt

I use the event to show a message when I press the ESC key, but it shows the alert twice. Where is the mistake?

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent event) {
        NativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
            if( nativeEvent.getKeyCode() == 27){
            Windows.alert("HELLO");
        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fires for both KeyDown and KeyUp events. You should do:

```
public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
    NativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
    if ("keydown".equals(nativeEvent.getType())) {
        if (nativeEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) {
            Windows.alert("HELLO");
        }
    }
}
```